# What functions in R can recursively "reduce" the rows of a dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, recursion, fold

What functions in R can recursively "reduce" the rows of a dataframe?  I'm thinking of a function like [`Reduce()`](https://search.r-project.org/R/refmans/base/html/funprog.html), but that accepts a dataframe instead of a vector, and a function that accepts each row of the dataframe and an accumulator.

Consider the following example that creates a dataframe that contains the price and quantity of a list of purchases and uses `Reduce()` to calculate the running total cost.

```r
purchases = data.frame(
  price = c(1.50, 1.75, 2.00, 2.10, 1.80),
  quantity = c(100, 80, 50, 20, 90)
)
print(purchases)
#>   price quantity
#> 1  1.50      100
#> 2  1.75       80
#> 3  2.00       50
#> 4  2.10       20
#> 5  1.80       90
purchase_costs <- purchases$quantity * purchases$price
print(purchase_costs)
#> [1] 150 140 100  42 162
total_cost <- Reduce(
  function(total_cost, cost) { total_cost + cost },
  purchase_costs,
  accumulate = TRUE
)
print(total_cost)
#> [1] 150 290 390 432 594
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

What functions in R similar to `Reduce()` might calculate this running total cost by recursively processing each purchase in the dataframe rather than each cost in a vector of costs?  Such a `Reduce()` function might resemble the following:

```r
total_cost <- Reduce(
  function(total_cost, purchase) { total_cost + purchase["quantity"] * purchase["price"] },
  purchases,
  accumulate = TRUE
)
```

Comment: `cumsum(purchases$quantity * purchases$price)`?

Comment: That does calculate a running total, but not for the rows in a dataframe and it doesn't use a custom function to calculate the sum.  I'm looking for a more generic reduction function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Reduce` by itself isn't going to operate row-wise like you want: it works well on a simple vector or `list`, but not on rows of a frame.

Try this frame-aware function:

```r
Reduce_frame <- function(data, expr, init) {
  expr <- substitute(expr)
  out <- rep(init[1][NA], nrow(data))
  for (rn in seq_len(nrow(data))) {
    out[rn] <- init <- eval(expr, envir = data[rn,])
  }
  out
}

Reduce_frame(purchases, init + quantity*price, init=0)
# [1] 150 290 390 432 594
```

Comment: Is it not possible to instruct `Reduce()` to pass the dataframe as an argument to the function?  Otherwise, the function applies only to an existing dataframe called "purchases" in the outer context.

Comment: `Reduce` doesn't work row-wise on frames. Is it your intent to repeat this function over multiple identically-structured frames?

Comment: Asked differently, how can this function be agnostic to the frame `purchases` while hard-coding `["quantity"]` and `["price"]`?

Comment: Yes, I was hoping to make it more reusable.  Can `Reduce()` operate on multiple equal-length vectors or on a vector of lists?  For a large dataframe, the overhead of converting the dataframe to a list vector may be too high, though.

Comment: The function could be specific to a purchase "structure", but this concept doesn't exist in R.

Comment: See my edit, perhaps it's closer to what you're suggesting.

Comment: This is closer to what I had in mind, though it iterates over the rows in the dataframe.  I guess it's not possible to use recursion.  Functions `substitute()` and `eval()` are new to me, but I think I understand how they work in this example.

Comment: I think your mention of `recursion` is a little unnecessary here, I think "reductive" is a better representation of the process. If you can explain why any of this should be recursive, then please try a different way of saying what should be recursive. FYI, while R does recursion as needed, it does not do "tail-recursion" efficiently, so often it is not the best approach from a performance/efficiency standpoint. If you can better explain why you think this is recursion, perhaps we can address (or adjust) it.

Comment: The cumulative sum in the example that I gave is a simpler function than the one that I actually need to calculate, but both are recursive in that the output of a calculation for one row serves as an input to the calculation for the next row.  I usually associate reduction or folding in a recursive context, but these can be implemented using iteration, too.

Comment: Good clarification, thanks. In that sense then I agree it can be termed as recursive; specifically, one way to approach it could be with recursion. In my experience, I tend to avoid recursion in R because it can go badly a little more easily than in languages that do better stack-management (i.e., implement good tail-recursion). Many simpler recursive algorithms can be unrolled (so to speak) into a reductive process (as here), and in many languages this does not necessarily involve a change in performance (just elegance of code). Glad it worked for you. (And I'm keeping this func around :-)

Comment: As I look at the code, it might do better to replace `...` with a simple `expr`, since I don't know how this would work when multiple arguments are provided (in the variadic sense).

Comment: FYI @DerekMahar, I edited it to clear up the ambiguity with variance `...`, as with quick testing and thinking, I don't know what it should be doing. This version (single `expr`ession) seems clearly in my head.

Comment: Thank you, @r2evans. I need to read about `substitute()` and `eval()`.  I'm still in the process of learning R and how I can use it to solve this problem.

Comment: `substitute` is a way to capture the expression *without evaluating it*, which is fairly important. For instance, when this function starts, the expression is `init + quantity*price`, but none of those symbols represent variables in the calling frame; if we look at `expr` without `substitute`, it will fail with `object 'init' not found` (or similar). Once we have the unevaluated expression, using it in `eval` is one start, but we need to define the "environment" in which those symbols are expected to resolve ... in this case, the specific row in `data`. Does that help?

Answer (score 1):

How's this?

```
library(tidyverse)

purchases %>% 
  mutate(cost = price * quantity) %>% 
  mutate(total_cost = cost + lag(cumsum(cost)))

  price quantity cost total_cost
1  1.50      100  150         NA
2  1.75       80  140        290
3  2.00       50  100        390
4  2.10       20   42        432
5  1.80       90  162        594
```

Comment: Shouldn't the first total_cost be 150? I'm looking for a general reduction function. I changed my question to make it more general. I think my original question was too specific to calculating a cumulative cost. The function that I actually need to apply is more complicated.