# Combining recursion with map - is reduce the solution?

Tags: r, loops, recursion, purrr

I am trying to avoid using a for loop at all costs in this example. Consider this simple case:

I have a vector `z` and an initial condition `b1`:

```
z <- 1:5
b1 <- 0
```

Consider also this simple function like adding:

```
f <- function(y, b){
 return(y + b)
}
```

I'd like to write a function that generates a sequence `S` as follows: the first element, call it `S[1]` is `f`'s output with the `y` argument as `z[1]` and the `b` argument as the initial condition `b1`. The second element `S[2]` is such that `S[2] = f(y = z[2], b = S[1])`. How can I?

Keep in mind that I don't want to use stuff like `cumsum` since my actual function `f` is more complicated
The desired output on this case would be the vector:

```
c(0 + 1,
1 + 2,
3 + 3,
6 + 4,
10 + 5)
```

Or `c(1, 3, 6, 10, 15)`

I thought about using `reduce` but I guess it only accepts deals with the recursive argument `b` and not the mapping part `y`

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid a `for` loop *"at all costs"*? Done correctly, `for` loops are unambiguous, clear, and as fast (if not faster) than some `apply`-like solutions.

Comment: @r2evans just for the sake of brevity

Comment: @r2evans and I guess for the sake of learning

Comment: @Ben you are right, I will correct this

Comment: You say `S[1] = z[1] + b1` and `S[2] = f(z[2], S[1])`, which to me means that `S` ranges from 1 to 5 along `z`. However, your expected output is length 6. I think this means either your formulation is missing something or your expected output is too long.

Comment: @r2evans just corrected it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```r
Reduce(function(prev, this) prev + this,
       1:5, init=0, accumulate=TRUE)[-1]
# [1]  1  3  6 10 15
```

You can easily use your own function in place of my anonymous function, I defined it like that to demonstrate which value is which: the first argument is your `S[n-1]`, the second is your `z[n]`.

The `[-1]` is because of this: *without* `init=`, the first call to function is effectively `f(prev=z[1], this=z[2])`, which is correct only when your `b1` is 0. If `b1` is ever anything else, then you must use `init=b1`. However, when using `init=`, it *effectively* prepends it to the input vector (your `z`). This means that the first call to the function is `f(prev=b1, this=z[1])` which is right, but it also means that the return value *includes* `b1` and is therefore too long. Fortunately, we can drop the first element very easily.

Lastly, the normal operation of `Reduce` is to only return the value from the last call to the function (ergo the *reduction* concept of `Reduce`); using `accumulate=` really means `Reduce` is a cumulative-operation function.

Comment: thanks! does this work if my function has other arguments that are constant across iterations? How could I change that?

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you mean. The anon-func must accept at least two arguments, where any args beyond the second either need to have default values or can be `missing(.)`. If you need any of the not-first-two arguments to vary, then you need something more. For that, I suggest trying to adapt a [recent answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70945868/3358272) that might support what you need.

Comment: they can be constant in my case. What do you mean by ```missing(.)```? just leave them in blank?

Comment: If they can be constant, then the function's first two arguments are used by `Reduce`, and any other arguments must rely on their default values. If they need to be set (to a static value), then if this function of yours is called `func`, then you need a wrapper: `Reduce(function(pr, th) func(pr, th, arg1=9, arg2=42), 1:5, init=0, accumulate=TRUE)[-1]`. Does that make sense?