# How to mask subsequences of string with a pattern string

Tags: r, string, string-matching

I have a main string that looks like this:

```
my_main <- "ABCDEFGHIJ"
```

What I want to do is to sequentially mask at every position with another pattern string:

```
my_pattern <- "x*x" # the length could be varied from 1 up to length of my_main
```

Every character that overlap with `*` will be kept, other will be replaced with `x`.

The final result is a vector of strings that contain these:

```
xBxDEFGHIJ
AxCxEFGHIJ
ABxDxFGHIJ
ABCxExGHIJ
ABCDxFxHIJ
ABCDExGxIJ
ABCDEFxHxJ
ABCDEFGxIx
```

Next if the pattern is

```
my_pattern <- "xx**x"
```

The result would be:

```
xxCDxFGHIJ
AxxDExGHIJ
ABxxEFxHIJ
ABCxxFGxIJ
ABCDxxGHxJ
ABCDExxHIx
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an approach along the same lines as r2evans' answer but relying on some `stringr` functions which should be more efficient than the base equivalents:

```
library(stringr)

f <- function(main, r_pattern) {
  shift <-  nchar(main) - nchar(r_pattern) + 1
  idx <- as.data.frame(str_locate_all(r_pattern, "[^*]+")[[1]])
  x_pattern <- str_split(r_pattern, "\\*+")[[1]]
  
  Reduce(
    function(x, y)
      `str_sub<-`(
        x,
        seq(idx$start[y], length.out = shift),
        seq(idx$end[y], length.out = shift),
        omit_na = FALSE,
        x_pattern[y]
      ),
    seq(nrow(idx)),
    init = main
  )
}

f("ABCDEFGHIJ", "x*x")
[1] "xBxDEFGHIJ" "AxCxEFGHIJ" "ABxDxFGHIJ" "ABCxExGHIJ" "ABCDxFxHIJ" "ABCDExGxIJ" "ABCDEFxHxJ" "ABCDEFGxIx"

f("ABCDEFGHIJ", "xx**x")
[1] "xxCDxFGHIJ" "AxxDExGHIJ" "ABxxEFxHIJ" "ABCxxFGxIJ" "ABCDxxGHxJ" "ABCDExxHIx"

# Edit after OP comment:
f(my_main, "KK**KRR")
[1] "KKCDKRRHIJ" "AKKDEKRRIJ" "ABKKEFKRRJ" "ABCKKFGKRR"
```

Comment: @RitchieSacaramento thanks. How can I modify your code so it can handle any character other than `x`; the asterisk (`*`) remains though, e.g. `KK**KRR`.

Comment: @scamander - I've edited the answer to use the regex `[^*]+` which means match any run of characters that aren't an asterisk.  Is that what you need?

Answer (score 5):

This might be a little over-complicated, but it's a start:

I'm going to reuse `Reduce_frame` from https://stackoverflow.com/a/70945868/3358272.

```r
Reduce_frame <- function(data, expr, init) {
  expr <- substitute(expr)
  out <- rep(init[1][NA], nrow(data))
  for (rn in seq_len(nrow(data))) {
    out[rn] <- init <- eval(expr, envir = data[rn,])
  }
  out
}
```

From here, let's split the pattern into a frame (for ease of access, if nothing else):

```r
repl <- subset(
  data.frame(p = strsplit(my_pattern, "")[[1]], i = seq_len(nchar(my_pattern))),
  p != "*")
repl
#   p i
# 1 x 1
# 3 x 3
```

From here, we can do it *once* with:

```r
tail(Reduce_frame(repl, `substring<-`(init, i, i, p), init = my_main), 1)
# [1] "xBxDEFGHIJ"
```

Which means we can iterate fairly easily:

```r
sapply(c(0, seq_len(nchar(my_main) - nchar(my_pattern))), function(offset) {
  tail(Reduce_frame(transform(repl, i = i + offset),
                    `substring<-`(init, i, i, p), init = my_main), 1)
})
# [1] "xBxDEFGHIJ" "AxCxEFGHIJ" "ABxDxFGHIJ" "ABCxExGHIJ" "ABCDxFxHIJ" "ABCDExGxIJ" "ABCDEFxHxJ" "ABCDEFGxIx"
```

To use your second pattern,

```r
my_pattern <- "xx**x" 
repl <- transform(...) # from above
## the rest of this code is unchanged from above
sapply(c(0, seq_len(nchar(my_main) - nchar(my_pattern))), function(offset) {
  tail(Reduce_frame(transform(repl, i = i + offset),
                    `substring<-`(init, i, i, p), init = my_main), 1)
})
# [1] "xxCDxFGHIJ" "AxxDExGHIJ" "ABxxEFxHIJ" "ABCxxFGxIJ" "ABCDxxGHxJ" "ABCDExxHIx"
```

---

So this can be easily functionized:

```r
Reduce_frame <- ... # defined above
func <- function(S, pattern) {
  stopifnot(nchar(S) >= nchar(pattern))
  repl <- subset(
    data.frame(p = strsplit(pattern, "")[[1]], i = seq_len(nchar(pattern))),
    p != "*")
  sapply(c(0, seq_len(nchar(S) - nchar(pattern))), function(offset) {
    tail(Reduce_frame(transform(repl, i = i + offset),
                      `substring<-`(init, i, i, p), init = S), 1)
  })
}

func("ABCDEFGHIJ", "x*x")
# [1] "xBxDEFGHIJ" "AxCxEFGHIJ" "ABxDxFGHIJ" "ABCxExGHIJ" "ABCDxFxHIJ" "ABCDExGxIJ" "ABCDEFxHxJ" "ABCDEFGxIx"
func("ABCDEFGHIJ", "xx**x")
# [1] "xxCDxFGHIJ" "AxxDExGHIJ" "ABxxEFxHIJ" "ABCxxFGxIJ" "ABCDxxGHxJ" "ABCDExxHIx"
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way using `strsplit`, `grepl`, and `paste`.

```
f <- \(mm, mp) {
    m <- el(strsplit(mm, ''))
    p <- el(strsplit(mp, '')) 
    i <- which(!grepl(p, pattern='\\*'))
    vapply(c(0L, seq_len(length(m) - max(i))), \(j) {
        m[i + j] <- p[i]
        paste(m, collapse='')
    }, vector('character', 1L))
}


f('ABCDEFGHIJ', 'x*x')
# [1] "xBxDEFGHIJ" "AxCxEFGHIJ" "ABxDxFGHIJ" "ABCxExGHIJ" "ABCDxFxHIJ"
# [6] "ABCDExGxIJ" "ABCDEFxHxJ" "ABCDEFGxIx"
f('ABCDEFGHIJ', 'x**x')
# [1] "xBCxEFGHIJ" "AxCDxFGHIJ" "ABxDExGHIJ" "ABCxEFxHIJ" "ABCDxFGxIJ"
# [6] "ABCDExGHxJ" "ABCDEFxHIx"
f('ABCDEFGHIJ', 'xx**x')
# [1] "xxCDxFGHIJ" "AxxDExGHIJ" "ABxxEFxHIJ" "ABCxxFGxIJ" "ABCDxxGHxJ"
# [6] "ABCDExxHIx"

f('ABCDEFGHIJ', 'kk**krr')
# [1] "kkCDkrrHIJ" "AkkDEkrrIJ" "ABkkEFkrrJ" "ABCkkFGkrr"
f('ABCDEFGHIJ', 'kk**kr*r')
# [1] "kkCDkrGrIJ" "AkkDEkrHrJ" "ABkkEFkrIr"
```

Comment: thanks. How can I modify your code so it can handle any character other than `x`; the asterisk (`*`) remains though, e.g. `KK**KRR`.

Comment: @scamander Please check my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is Ruby code that produces the desired result. I am presenting it in the event that a reader wishes to convert it to R, possibly with modification, of course.

You should be able to read the code even if you don't know Ruby, as long as you understand that:

- `'abc'.size` returns `3`;
- `0..8` is a range of integers between `0` and `8`, inclusive;
- `'abc' << 'd'` returns `'abcd'`;
- `7.modulo(3)` returns `1`;
- `'abcd'[2]` returns `'c'`, `2` being an index; and
- `s == 'x' ? 'x' : my_main[j]` reads, "if the string `s` (which will be `'x'` or `'*'`) equals `'x'`  return `'x'`, else return the character of `my_main` at index `j`.

The Ruby code (somewhat simplified from what would normally be written) is as follows.

```
def doit(my_main, my_pattern)
  msz = my_main.size
  psz = my_pattern.size
  (0..msz-psz).map do |i|
    s = ''
    (0..msz-1).each do |j|
      s << (my_pattern[(j-i).modulo(msz)] == 'x' ? 'x' : my_main[j])
    end
    s
  end
end
```