# In R , a calculation question like Solver

Tags: r, solver

There are warehouse figures in below dataframe, currently know the data `ship_in` and `ship_out_forecast`.
Now I want to fix `ship_out_forecast` figures, make it's reasonable (the result as 'ship_out_forecast_checked' in attached image)

Below are the constraint condition：

1. cumsum(ship_in)-cumsum(ship_out_forecast_checked)>= 0
2. ship_out_forecast_checked>0
3. 'ship_out_forecast_checked'<='ship_out_forecast'

```r
library(tidyverse)
mdate <- c(44593,44594,44595,44596,44597,44598,44599,44600,44601,44602,44603,44604,44605,44606,44607,44593,44594,44595,44596,44597,44598,44599,44600,44601,44602,44603,44604,44605,44606,44607)
category <- c("A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B")
ship_in <- c(20,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,7,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,7,30,0,0,0,0,25,0,0,0,0,0)
ship_out_forecast <- c(12,15,13,11,3,5,8,14,8,11,1,9,16,9,3,29,10,28,0,21,12,23,22,23,19,1,2,16,15,9)

warehouse_data <- data.frame(mdate,category,ship_in,ship_out_forecast) %>% 
  mutate(mdate=as.Date(mdate,origin='1900-1-1'))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using https://stackoverflow.com/a/70945868/3358272 as a starting point with `Reduce_frame`:

```r
Reduce_frame <- function(data, expr, init) {
  expr <- substitute(expr)
  out <- rep(init[1][NA], nrow(data))
  for (rn in seq_len(nrow(data))) {
    out[rn] <- init <- eval(expr, envir = data[rn,])
  }
  out
}
```

Assuming you want to group by `category` (which can be removed easily if not), we can do this:

```r
warehouse_data %>%
  group_by(category) %>%
  mutate(
    ending_inventory = Reduce_frame(cur_data(), max(0, init + ship_in - ship_out_forecast), init = 0)
  ) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 30 x 5
#    mdate      category ship_in ship_out_forecast ending_inventory
#    <date>     <chr>      <dbl>             <dbl>            <dbl>
#  1 2022-02-03 A             20                12                8
#  2 2022-02-04 A              0                15                0
#  3 2022-02-05 A              0                13                0
#  4 2022-02-06 A              0                11                0
#  5 2022-02-07 A              5                 3                2
#  6 2022-02-08 A              0                 5                0
#  7 2022-02-09 A              0                 8                0
#  8 2022-02-10 A              0                14                0
#  9 2022-02-11 A              0                 8                0
# 10 2022-02-12 A              7                11                0
# # ... with 20 more rows
```

Comment: Thanks, that's great.  Could you help to explain the function Reduce_frame  ? it's looks very difficult  .    especially "out[rn] <- init <- eval(expr, envir = data[rn,])"....

Comment: I understand Reduce_frame manipulate the data by record one by one.  What's make it have  running calculation capability ......?

Comment: It goes row-by-row, and uses the reserved `init` reference in the expression `init + ship_in - ship_out_forecast`. That's an expression, where the first symbol `init` is the result from the previous row's value, and the rest of the symbols are assumed to be available in the frame.

Comment: I understand now and thanks for your replay.  From the resule 'out <- rep(init[1][NA], nrow(data))'  equals  'rep(NA, nrow(data))',  why use  'init[1][NA]' for the first parameter ？ Thanks!

Comment: It's not always *strictly* necessary, but ... in R, there are at least six types of `NA`, and some R tools actually complain if you're using the wrong one. (Okay, it's mostly tidyverse or `data.table` that will complain.) Using `NA` is *usually* coerced into the right one, but technically that is the `logical` variant; using `x[1][NA]` should *always* give the appropriate variant of `NA`. It is likely overkill in many situations, it's just a little defensive technique I use.